How can I build a query for date range in opensearch such that the nested values of those must also satisfy?
I have an opensearch document for which represents a hotel/staycation property. It has the following structure:
{
 "place": {},
 "calendar": [{"calendar_date": "2024-01-05", days_available": 1}, {"calendar_date": "2024-01-06", days_available": 2}, {"calendar_date": "2024-01-07", days_available": 3}]
}

the calender property above is of nested type.
I want to create a query which would search all the documents which satisfies the existence of a given calendar_date range m-n and days_available greater than a value n. Meaning, that for all the dates between m and n including m,n must have days_available greater than n.
I tried the following query and it is working fine, but I need to give a range instead of creating nested query of each of the dates between m-n. As my solution seems a pretty inefficient if I want to give a very large range.
{
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "calendar",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "calendar.days_available": {
                                                "gt": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "calendar.calendar_date": "2024-08-13"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "avg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "calendar",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "calendar.days_available": {
                                                "gt": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "calendar.calendar_date": "2024-08-14"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "avg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "calendar",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "calendar.days_available": {
                                                "gt": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "calendar.calendar_date": "2024-08-15"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "avg"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

